# Google Chrome Extension - Content Security Policy

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a Google Chrome Extension. In my manifest.json, I have the following line;

```
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com https://api.uber.com; object-src 'self'",
```

When I do an jQuery Ajax call to "https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/time", I am getting;

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
albooker.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/time...... 

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://elgjhbhandpgpankfcdmlmndilgledee' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

AJAX code;

```
$.ajax({ 
type: "GET", 
dataType: "json", 
url: uberURL, 
success: function( jsondata ) { 
// Call function to display details 
alert(JSON.stringify(jsondata)); 
}
```

I have pasted the generated URL uberURL into a browser and that returns the expected data. –

Am I doing this the correct way? Thanks

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to POST instead of GET. Can you show your AJAX code?

Comment: I was doing a POST instead of a GET. I have changed in and reduced the errors from 2 to 1;

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/time?start_latitude=51.5269722&start_longitude=-0.1394349&server_token=xxxxxxx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://elgjhbhandpgpankfcdmlmndilgledee' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Please edit your question; code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: Quick check, have you reloaded the extension after modifying the CSP string?

Comment: Yep, both reload and deleted and readded.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: @AndrewSpiers Sorry I didn't realize the obvious. rsanchez is correct; you don't even need the CSP entry for Uber.

Answer (score 1):

Adding URLs to the Content Security Policy allows you to **execute code** from those websites. If you want to be able to make Ajax calls instead, you need to add them to the [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) section of your manifest:

```
permisions: ["https://api.uber.com/"]
```

Comment: Darn, what a brain fart on my part not to understand that.